# Merge non-existing node and return the source node in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using neo4j as my database in my little application.
My application is about managing candidates' CV (Resume').

This is my diagram :

[image: CV Management]

For now, what I'm doing is to add a project with a list of skills that the project uses.

This is my neo4j query:

```
MATCH (user: User)
WHERE (user.Id = "74994fd8-40bb-48e8-adf1-bc11eeb6c035")
WITH user
MERGE (project: Project {Id: '02d5ad72-036c-47e9-a366-d5ca4a3e66e2'})
ON CREATE
SET project = {
  Id: "02d5ad72-036c-47e9-a366-d5ca4a3e66e2",
  Name: "VINCI GTR",
  Description: "Description of VINCI GTR",
  StartedTime: 0.0
}
MERGE (user)-[:DID_PROJECT]->(project)
WITH project, user
MATCH (user)-[:HAS_SKILL]->(skill: Skill)
WHERE skill.Id IN []
MERGE (project)-[:USED_SKILL]->(skill)
RETURN project
```

In my query, I use: `WHERE skill.Id IN []` to make sure my skills list is empty, because I want to simulate a situation that there is no skill available.

When I run the command, I cannot receive the newly created project, even it has been created in database. I have this result instead:

[image: Neo4j result]

How can I:

- Create the relationships between user and skill when skill is available and -
- Skip this operation if no skill is not available.
- Return newly created `Project` instance ?

Thanks

Comment: I think your first bullet should be "Create the relationships between **project** and skill when skill is available ...", correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `MATCH` clause that fails to match aborts the rest of the query (and the query will return nothing).

The following snippet will never match anything, since it is trying to match `user` nodes that have a related `skill` node whose `Id` value matches a nonexistent value (which makes no sense):

```
MATCH (user)-[:HAS_SKILL]->(skill: Skill)
WHERE skill.Id IN []
```

To only create the `USED_SKILL` relationship if `user` does not have a skill, do this:

```
MATCH (user: User)
WHERE user.Id = "74994fd8-40bb-48e8-adf1-bc11eeb6c035"
MERGE (project: Project {Id: '02d5ad72-036c-47e9-a366-d5ca4a3e66e2'})
ON CREATE
  SET project += {
    Name: "VINCI GTR",
    Description: "Description of VINCI GTR",
    StartedTime: 0.0
  }
MERGE (user)-[:DID_PROJECT]->(project)
WITH project, user
WHERE SIZE((user)-[:HAS_SKILL]->()) = 0
MERGE (project)-[:USED_SKILL]->(skill)
RETURN project
```

This query does a degree-ness check on each `user` node to find the ones that have no `HAS_SKILL` relationships (we deliberately omit the `:Skill` label from the opposite node in the pattern, which is a kind of hack to cause the Cypher planner to generate a more efficient operation). Also, we use `SET +=` instead of `SET =` so that we don't replace all the node properties, allowing us to avoid having to overwrite the `Id` value with the same value.

#### By the way:

The `HAS_SKILL_CATEGORY` relationship seems to be redundant. If a user's skills can all be reached via `HAS_SKILL` relationships, then you can already get that user's categories via something like this:

```
MATCH (user: User)-[:HAS_SKILL]->()-[:BE_IN_SKILL_CATEGORY]->(c)
WHERE user.Id = "74994fd8-40bb-48e8-adf1-bc11eeb6c035"
RETURN c;
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution.
Before your answer, I have to turn on the lenient match operation for neo4j by setting it in the configuration file. It worked, however, I don't like touching the configuration file much.

Comment: If you are talking about the "lenient" configuration setting in OGM, see [this closed issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/424). There is some agreement that the default behavior *should be* "more lenient", but for possibly overall practical reasons, it has been decided to make it not that way. But most people will probably have no problems using the "lenient" setting.